# SetTargetProperty Method in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm currently using Ms Visual Studio 2012, windows store application to create a pacman game. I've been facing some errors shown below. Was hoping if anyone could help me out with solving it? Thanks..

Code:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(leftAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
```

Error showing:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Timeline,
>   string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Hi @SonerGonul, the error showing is "The best overloaded method match for 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Timeline, string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @fafarifah Is your Canvas Element named Canvas?

Comment: @letiagoalves Yup, I even tried changing my canvas name and yet I'm still facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Metro (confusingly) has a different signature. Rather than a PropertyPath it takes a string :/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settargetproperty.aspx